# MVC 4 Open Jquery Dialog on same page

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have many(5-7 or more) links on a page, I am showing link's data in a dialog box, but when clicking on link it open the link in the window as well displays data in the Dialog,
please tell me the right way to display data only in the Dialog Box
Thanks.
I am using the following code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var id = @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PK);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/controller/method/?id="+id,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#dialog").html(data);
                    }
                });
        });
     </script>
```

Please tell me the right way to code...Thanks

Comment: have you added jquery ui css file? if yes then after this line $("#dialog").html(data); $("#dialog").dialog('open');

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the default behavoiur of link(opening in window) by calling `preventDefault()`

Assuming your HTML Look like below

```
<a class="dialog-link" href="url1">Link 1</a>
<a class="dialog-link" href="url2">Link 1</a>
```

and in JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
     $('a.dialog-link').click(function(e){
           var id = @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PK);
            $.ajax({
                url: "/controller/method/?id="+id,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#dialog").html(data);
                }
            });
         e.preventDefault();
     });
    });
 </script>
```